# Стилистическое оформление прямой речи

Tags: прямая-речь

Как, по Вашему мнению, лучше в данном случае оформить предложения? Уместна ли здесь прямая речь или она стилистически не подходит?

В статье встречаются несколько "высказываний".

Возникает вопрос: «Относится фланец к элементу оборудования или нет?»

Естественно, у производителей продукции возникает законный вопрос: «Нужно ли разрабатывать обоснование безопасности и проводить расчет на прочность деталей, выпускаемых строго по ГОСТ?»

Т. к. это обязательное требование ТР ТС 032/2013, то сертификационные центры дружно, в один голос заявляют: «Нужно».

По моему мнению, прямая речь здесь не нужна... Но является ли ошибкой ее оформление?

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что по стилю прямая речь здесь вполне уместна. Но вот по части понимания первую фразу лучше сделать косвенной.

> Возникает вопрос: «Относится фланец к элементу оборудования или нет?»

*Возникает вопрос, относится фланец к элементу оборудования или нет?*
или даже
*Возникает вопрос, относится ли фланец к элементу оборудования, или нет?*

Последний вариант встречает сопротивление пуристов от грамматики, которые не любят союза "*ли (...), или*", хотя на мой вкус он и напрашивается именно при таком построении фразы. Только поэтому не рекомендую второй вариант как единственный.

> Естественно, у производителей продукции возникает законный вопрос: «Нужно ли разрабатывать обоснование безопасности и проводить расчет на прочность деталей, выпускаемых строго по ГОСТ?»

Здесь нормально, прямая речь здесь именно вопрос - и это слово её же, прямую речь, предваряет. Не вижу причин что-то менять.

> Т. к. это обязательное требование ТР ТС 032/2013, то сертификационные центры дружно, в один голос заявляют: «Нужно».

Здесь, конечно, можно выразиться и через косвенную "заявляют, что нужно", но стилистически, с учетом полемического характера материала (не ошибся?), здесь прямая речь много лучше. (ср. «*Партия сказала "Надо! - Комсомол ответил "Есть!"*» - при всей идеологической спорности посыла, в выразительности средств примеру отказать  нельзя).

*На всякий случай: все сказанное - личное мнение, вкусовщина. Вопросы стилистики, читабельности, доходчивости и т. п. обычно решаются на субъективном уровне, устраивать многочасовой разбор полетов с привлечением авторитетов и нормативных актов не вижу смысла.*

Пунктуационных проблем не вижу ни в одном примере. А что Вас напугало-то в оформлении прямой речи?

Comment: Простите за off topic, прям не знаю, где спросить... Потом удалю обязательно. Как мне настроить время, кто-то знает? А то он показывает время по Гринвичу (GMT или UTC). Короче, на 3 часа меньше.

Comment: А ***где*** он время показывает? Или - кто он?

Comment: Ну, "он" это я так сказал, образно.))) В общем, когда наводишь на "отвечен, задан или изменён x часов (минут, дней) назад" в ответе или вопросе, появляются время с датой, вот там.

Comment: А, это... Боюсь, что не поправите. Это прямая ссылка еа поле в базе, вряд ли её в принципе пересчитывают. А чем она вас так напрягает, ну Гринвич - и Гринвич. Ладно бы еще с годом путалась, а три часа для архивного вопроса, которому уже год может быть и более, - не критично, имхо.

Comment: Убедили — постараюсь привыкнуть!)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Отдельное спасибо за пример с запятой - всегда хотела точно узнать, можно ли так оформлять... Значит, допускается вариативность.

Comment: Напугало именно отсутствие автора... Видно, что здесь не прямая речь, а просто предложение, а последнем случае действительно можно просто заменить на _"заявляют. что нужно"_.

Comment: *Значит, допускается вариативность* - ***мной*** допускается )))

Comment: Alenka, здесь такая штука происходит, что, если вдуматься, два-три автора сознательно противоречат друг другу. Если Вас убеждают все три, а то и больше, то у Вас скоро все смешается. Надо какой-то одной линии придерживаться в части методики. Я всегда стоял на том, что даже правильная рекомендация при путанном (тем более - неправильном) объяснении только вредит. Вы это учтите ))). Не стоит всем писать, что вы со всеми соглашаетесь. Не имею ничего против, если вы будете со мной спорить или закидаете меня вопросами по существу. Но вот этикетного поддакивания не люблю.

Comment: Конкретно, мне совсем не нравится поход Sergey'а, который просто говорит какие-то абстрактные вещи, правильные они или нет - сказать трудно, но ценность их весьма сомнительна. Ибо построены они исключительно на высказываниях "я так считаю". Такой подход приемлем только от опытного и авторитетного человек - и только в вопросах стилистики.

Comment: Тогда у меня, пожалуй, есть вопрос. Вы хотите сказать, что в предложении _"Возникает вопрос, относится ли фланец к элементу оборудования, или нет?"_ три простых предложения? Мне кажется, что здесь скорее однородные члены _(относится или не относится)_. Где-то встречала ссылку, где приводились примеры, когда перед  _или_  в таком случае ставилась запятая, но это, кажется, не тот случай.

Answer (score 3):

Оформить дословное высказывание позволяется **разными способами** (здесь нет жестких правил), но **выбор всегда делается с учетом влияния различных факторов** (смысловых, интонационных).

1) Думаю, что передавать  **содержание вопроса** с помощью прямой речи  в двух первых примерах не стоит, здесь обычно используется БСП, например:

**Возникает вопрос:** а правильно ли это вообще ― тратить бюджетные деньги на промышленные стандарты, по которым работает частный бизнес? **И здесь возникает вопрос**: что же предпринять, чтобы избежать проблем в производственной, финансовой и управленческой цепочках и снизить расходы на покрытие рисков?

(По определению, прямая речь - это дословная передача чужого высказывания, сопровождаемая словами автора).

2)  Т. к. это обязательное требование ТР ТС 032/2013, то сертификационные центры дружно, в один голос заявляют: «Нужно».

**Здесь прямую речь (с двоеточием) желательно оставить,** так как такое оформление лучше (выразительнее, эмоциональнее) описывает ситуацию (центры именно заявляют); кроме того, здесь  уместно сделать паузу, которую передает именно двоеточие.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я вот тоже склоняюсь к тому, чтобы все-таки прямую речь в двух местах убрать...

Answer (score 2):

Прямая речь здесь явно не подходит. По причине отсутствия ее, прямой речи, автора.
Достаточно просто убрать кавычки. Не нужно оформлять как косвенную.

Да, и прописные буквы в начале, естественно, тоже надо убрать.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Тоже склоняюсь к этому варианту. Про буквы знаю :)